# JavaScript - Saving Result

Tags: html

I have this,

http://dev.phantomore.com/simple.html

Right now,but it dosent save when ever I reload or look on a different computer

I tried many solutions in other forums including stack overflow.
But all didn't work, for some reason.
And what if two or more people save at the same time? will that casue a problem?

Comment: You aren't _saving_ anything anywhere. You're only modifying the value on the page with Javascript. To _save_ something on a webpage (outside of the sourcecode with a text editor) you'll need to look at using server-side technology. You cannot save on the client side with Javascript alone.

Answer (score 1):

You need some server side code to do that.

1. Set up a ASP.NET or PHP server.
2. Create a form in your html. Submit it to the server on change of the value.
3. Handle the saving on the server.

Another option to save this just locally is [WebDB](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/), which is a new HTML5 feature to create a mini-database on the client.